# perl simple efficiency and readability

Tags: perl, performance

I have a question on efficiency and readability in perl

I have a variable that can take on one of several values (5-6). Sometimes I want to check if this is a specific value, sometimes I want to check if it is one of several choices. I am making this sort of decision in many places in my code (in different functions), and I would like to make this as 'tight' as possible.

for example, say

```
my $mode; # can be any of qw(one two three four five six)
if ($mode eq 'one') {
    #do code
}

if ($mode eq 'one' or $mode eq 'two' or $mode eq 'three') {
    #do more code
}
```

This of course is not my real code, and with meaningful variable names, my if statements are getting quite long and wrap on several lines.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "tight"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `List::MoreUtils` module has the `any` function, which is like a short-circuiting `grep`:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/any/;

say "correct mode" if any { $_ eq $mode } qw/one two three/;
```

That said, you can still use `grep`, but that always tests all elements, whereas `any` aborts after the first matching element:

```
say "correct mode" if grep { $_ eq $mode } qw/one two three/;
```

Answer (score 3):

An idea.

```
my %please_name_me;
$please_name_me{$_}++ for qw(one two three);
if ($please_name_me{$mode}) {
    #do something
}
```

Otherwise I like using whitespace:

```
if (
    'one' eq $mode or
    'two' eq $mode or
    'three' eq $mode
) {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options (TMTOWDI).  Here are two of the simplest:

```
if ($mode =~ /^(?one|two|three)$/) { ... }

if (grep { $mode eq $_ } qw(one two three)) { ... }
```

With a little setup beforehand you can make it rather more efficient.  Do this once:

```
 my @modes = qw(one two three);
 my %modes;
 @modes{@modes} = @modes;
```

Then your check becomes simply:

```
if ($modes{$mode}) { ... }
```

Comment: `return` inside `grep` is sketchy. That makes it return from the enclosing subroutine; it is not a way to break out of a `grep` operation.

Comment: @mob Removed that bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a nice job for *smart match*, but the operator has been marked experimental and may be removed from later versions of Perl.

`List::Util` has the `any` operator. However, be very careful. The `List::Util` is a standard Perl module since at least Perl 5.8.8. Unfortunately, the nice `any` operator isn't included. You need to update this module in order to use `any`. However, the `first` operator may be good enough and that's part of the package:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use List::Util qw(first);

use constant VALID_VALUES => qw(one two three four five);

for my $value ( qw(zero one two three four five six) ) {
    if ( first { $value eq $_ } VALID_VALUES ) {
        say "$value is in the list!";
    }
    else {
        say "Nope. $value is not";
    }
}
```

Since you have `use List::Util qw(first);` in your program, user should realize that `first` is from the `List::Util` package and they can use `perldoc List::Util` to look it up.

You can also just use `grep` and forget about `List::Util`:

```
for my $value ( qw(zero one two three four five six) ) {
    if ( grep { $value eq $_ } VALID_VALUES ) {
        say "$value is in the list!";
    }
    else {
        say "Nope. $value is not";
    }
}
```

What you shouldn't do is use a complex regular expression or a if/else chain. These aren't necessarily any clearer and make your program harder to understand:

```
if ( $value =~ /^(one|two|three|four|five)$/ ) {

if ( $value eq "one" or $value eq "two" or $value eq "three" ... ) {
```

If you decide to change the valid list of values, you would have to go through your entire program to search for them. This is why I made them a *constant*. There's only one place in the program where they have to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Perl 5.10 or later, you can use [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) operator:

```
if ($mode ~~ ['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

Comment: The _smart match_ operator has practically been deprecated ([marked _experimental_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental)) and may be removed from later versions of Perl. It was fun while it lasted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many, many combinations to check, consider translating $mode to a numbered bit:

```
if 'one' -> $modeN = 1
if 'two' -> $modeN = 2
if 'three' -> $modeN = 4  etc.
```

To check just 'one', `if ($modeN == 1) {...`

To check 'one', 'two', or 'three', `if ($modeN & 7) {...`

To check 'two' or 'three', `if ($modeN & 6) {...`

To check 'one' OR ('two' AND 'three'), `if ($modeN & 1 || &modeN & 6) {...`

Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess it is because Phil misunderstood your question. You don't have combinations. `$mode` can take ONLY 1 out of 6 values, NOT combinations of these values.

Comment: Is that really worth downvoting? Some of you people are really obnoxious about this! Changing to bits is still usable even if you will have only one at a time, and is expandable in the future to multiples. At least I said, "Does that work for you?" rather than proclaiming, "Here is the one and only true answer -- behold it and weep, all others!"